# Excel vba - Is it possible to make option buttons independent without group boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to check multiples option buttons, and the only way I found for doing this is using group boxes. But these boxes aren’t invisible. Is there then a way to have it work as if there was group boxes around each group of buttons ? Or is there a way to make group boxes become invisible? I hope my question I clear enough for anybody to help me

Comment: What do you mean by group "boxes"? You can create a group handling their `GroupName` property. Nothing is visible, from this point of view. You can use as many such option buttons you want, but if not creating groups, all of them will act as being in a group. I mean if you check one of them, all the other will be unchecked. What do you want accomplishing, in fact?

Comment: What you said is what I'm trying to do, but my option buttons are directly on the excel sheet, and I don't know where to go to handle the properties

Comment: Are you trying to deal with Form Option Buttons? If yes, please try using ActiveX Option Buttons. They have a `GroupName` property and offer more flexibility, events etc.. Only now I understand what you meant by 'boxes'...

Comment: Are form option buttons the buttons that are put on userforms ? What I wanna do is : In the menu developer take the "option button" and place it on the worksheet, and have a few, and having them in different groups without having the item "group box" around them. Is this clear ?

Comment: It is, but isn't it clear what I suggested? When you are in 'Developer' Tab, pressing 'Insert' you may choose form Form or ActiveX controls. Try forgetting about Form controls. If you select an ActiveX Option button there is no need to put them on a frame, in order to set groups.

Comment: im on Mac, in "insert" I only have procedure, module and class module. Maybe that's the problem ?

Comment: Maybe... I do not know how MAC interface looks, from this point of view. But I think ActiveX controls have to exist. You must search on internet about he necessary way to use them...

Comment: i don't know if I can add screenshots to my messages

Comment: It looks that ActiveX controls are not supported in Excel MAC versions...

Comment: I'm thinking of something, does each option button has a name, and thus in the developer window I can give them a group instead of using the group box on the worksheet ?

Comment: If the Form controls behave as in Windows, it is not possible, I am afraid.

Comment: ok well thanks for your help ill try to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the property **GroupName**

when you set the same name the checkboxes or optinbuttons you can control the behaviour as you need

I hope be useful

Good Luck

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I want to use the buttons directly on the sheet and not in a user form (im on Mac and don't have access to user forms)

Comment: I guess, you should do it by code, validating control names or the text displayed, location or some value you can take from the control.

Comment: thank you, I don't know how to do, I'll check if I can find, or maybe I can get a link to a vid or something ?